# Nodemailer wont send email. I am getting Error , No recipients defined

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have this problem. I created a function to use Nodemailer to send emails.
it is supposed to send emails to two parties. one is the supposed admin email and the other is the normal user email respectively.

For some reason, it does not send emails, but saves information directly inside the Database which is supposed to do. But the email part, Noway it does not send emails.

My code is looking like this

```
import AdminListModel from "../../model/AdminUserList/AdminUserList.js";
import SuperAdminListModel from "../../model/SuperAdminModel/SuperAdminModel.js";
import services from "../../utils/services.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

function getAdminEmail(){
    SuperAdminListModel.find({}).exec(function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        } else {
            //res.json({ message: 'OK', data: users[0].superadmin_email })
            console.log(users[0].superadmin_email);
            return users[0].superadmin_email;
        }
    })
}

//getAdminEmail();

const dispatch_emails =(admin_email, email, fullname, company_name) =>{
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: '587',
        auth: {
            user: '*************@gmail.com',
            pass: '*************'
        },
        secureConnection: 'false',
        tls: {
            ciphers: 'SSLv3',
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: '************@gmail.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Account Registration Successful!',
        html: '<h3>Attention,' + fullname + ' , </h3><p><h3>Your Account has been successfully setup.</h3></p><p> Please allow a maximum of 24 - 48 Hours for Review and succesful setup and approval of your online account.</p></br>Regards,</br> Online Services.'
    };

    const AdminNotifyEmail = {
        from: '**************@gmail.com',
        to: admin_email,
        subject: 'Account Registration for ' + email + ', with Fullname : ' + fullname + ' (' + company_name + ')',
        html: '<h3>Attention Admin , </h3><p>A new User has registered his Access with the following Information: </br> <strong>Username : ' + email + '</strong></br><strong>Company Name : ' + company_name + '</strong></br><strong>Date of Registration: ' + (new Date()).toLocaleString() + '</strong></br>Regards</br>Online Services.</p>'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: info, message: 'OK' });
    })

    transporter.sendMail(AdminNotifyEmail, function (error, info) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: info, message: 'OK' });
    })
}

export const RegisterAdminUser = async (req, res) => {
    const existingUser = await AdminListModel.findOne({
        $or: [{ email: req.body.email }],
    });
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(409).json({ errors: { email: "User already exists" } });
    }
    const newUser = new AdminListModel({
        company_name: req.body.company_name,
        fullname: req.body.fullname,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
        timezone: req.body.timezone
    });

    const admin_email = getAdminEmail();

    const payload1 = {
        _id: newUser._id,
    };

    await newUser.save()
    const token = jwt.sign(payload1, services.JWT_KEY, {
        expiresIn: 31556926,
    });

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) {
            // console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        }
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
            if (err) {
                // console.log("err: ", err);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
            }
            newUser.password = hash;
            await newUser.save();
            dispatch_emails(admin_email, newUser.email, newUser.fullname, newUser.company_name);
            const payload = {
                _id: newUser._id,
                email: req.body.email,
            };
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, services.JWT_KEY, {
                expiresIn: 31556926,
            });
        })
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: "User registered Successfully",
            token: token,
            user: newUser,
        });
    })
};


export const listUsers = async (req, res) => {
    /*const userId = req.query.userId || req.user._id;
    // console.log(userId);
    const currentUser = await SuperAdminListModel.findById(userId);

    if (!currentUser) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    */
    AdminListModel.find({}).exec(function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        } else {
            res.json({ message: 'OK', data: users })
        }
    })
};
```

Is there something i am not doing rightly? Kindly let me know.

**Edits**

I am trying to Edit now, and it runs a new Error

the function to get admin Email is looking like this

```
await function getAdminEmail(){
    return SuperAdminListModel.find({}).exec(function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        } else {
            res.json({ data: users[0].superadmin_email })
        }
    })
}
```

Testing it , it says `getAdminEmail()` is not defined. Please I need help here anyone.

My code Looks like this now.

```
import AdminListModel from "../../model/AdminUserList/AdminUserList.js";
import SuperAdminListModel from "../../model/SuperAdminModel/SuperAdminModel.js";
import services from "../../utils/services.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";


const dispatch_emails =(admin_email, email, fullname, company_name) =>{
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: '587',
        auth: {
            user: '****************@gmail.com',
            pass: '************'
        },
        secureConnection: 'false',
        tls: {
            ciphers: 'SSLv3',
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: '***********************@gmail.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Account Registration Successful!',
        html: '<h3>Attention,' + fullname + ' , </h3><p><h3>Your Account has been successfully setup.</h3></p><p> Please allow a maximum of 24 - 48 Hours for Review and succesful setup and approval of your online account.</p></br>Regards,</br> Online Services.'
    };

    const AdminNotifyEmail = {
        from: '************@gmail.com',
        to: admin_email,
        subject: 'Account Registration for ' + email + ', with Fullname : ' + fullname + ' (' + company_name + ')',
        html: '<h3>Attention Admin , </h3><p>A new User has registered his Access with the following Information: </br> <strong>Username : ' + email + '</strong></br><strong>Company Name : ' + company_name + '</strong></br><strong>Date of Registration: ' + (new Date()).toLocaleString() + '</strong></br>Regards</br>Online Services.</p>'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: info, message: 'OK' });
    })

    transporter.sendMail(AdminNotifyEmail, function (error, info) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: info, message: 'OK' });
    })
}

export const RegisterAdminUser = async (req, res) => {
    const superadmin_email = await SuperAdminListModel.find({});
    const existingUser = await AdminListModel.findOne({
        $or: [{ email: req.body.email }],
    });
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(409).json({ errors: { email: "User already exists" } });
    }
    const newUser = new AdminListModel({
        superadmin_email : superadmin_email.superadmin_email,
        company_name: req.body.company_name,
        fullname: req.body.fullname,
        email: req.body.email,
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
        timezone: req.body.timezone
    });

    const payload1 = {
        _id: newUser._id,
    };

    await newUser.save()
    const token = jwt.sign(payload1, services.JWT_KEY, {
        expiresIn: 31556926,
    });

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) {
            // console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        }
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
            if (err) {
                // console.log("err: ", err);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
            }
            newUser.password = hash;
            await newUser.save();
            dispatch_emails(superadmin_email, newUser.email, newUser.fullname, newUser.company_name);
            const payload = {
                _id: newUser._id,
                email: req.body.email,
            };
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, services.JWT_KEY, {
                expiresIn: 31556926,
            });
        })
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: "User registered Successfully",
            token: token,
            user: newUser,
        });
    })
};


export const listUsers = async (req, res) => {
    /*const userId = req.query.userId || req.user._id;
    // console.log(userId);
    const currentUser = await SuperAdminListModel.findById(userId);

    if (!currentUser) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    */
    AdminListModel.find({}).exec(function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        } else {
            res.json({ message: 'OK', data: users })
        }
    })
};
```

Now i am getting this Error

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1348]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend>code .

D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend>npm start

> onepercentcrm@1.0.0 start D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend
> node app.js

Listening on port 5000
Connected to DB
POST /api/register_auth/register-adminuser1 200 741.816 ms - 458
file:///D:/node_apps/Backend-node_backend/controller/AdminUserListController/AdminUserListController.js:45
        if (error) throw error;
                   ^

Error: Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 553-5.1.3 The recipient address <'*****************@gmail.com'> is not a valid
553-5.1.3 RFC-5321 address. Learn more at
553 5.1.3  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 go10sm127840ejc.115 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1626:28)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1579:30)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:947:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:189:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10) {
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  response: "553-5.1.3 The recipient address <'e.iwuagwung@gmail.com'> is not a valid\n" +
    '553-5.1.3 RFC-5321 address. Learn more at\n' +
    '553 5.1.3  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 go10sm127840ejc.115 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 553,
  command: 'RCPT TO',
  rejected: [ "'*****************@gmail.com'" ],
  rejectedErrors: [
    Error: Recipient command failed: 553-5.1.3 The recipient address <'*****************@gmail.com'> is not a valid
    553-5.1.3 RFC-5321 address. Learn more at
    553 5.1.3  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 go10sm127840ejc.115 - gsmtp
        at SMTPConnection._formatError (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
        at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1612:24)
        at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1579:30)
        at SMTPConnection._processResponse (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:947:20)
        at SMTPConnection._onData (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
        at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:189:44)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
        at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
        at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
        at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10) {
      code: 'EENVELOPE',
      response: "553-5.1.3 The recipient address <'*****************@gmail.com'> is not a valid\n" +
        '553-5.1.3 RFC-5321 address. Learn more at\n' +
        '553 5.1.3  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 go10sm127840ejc.115 - gsmtp',
      responseCode: 553,
      command: 'RCPT TO',
      recipient: "'*****************@gmail.com'"
    }
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! onepercentcrm@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the onepercentcrm@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\emi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-02T16_01_26_359Z-debug.log

D:\node_apps\Backend-node_backend>
```

Comment: You should both remove your password from this answer and change it. Don't include real credentials in a Stack Overflow post as bots will pick up on these.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getAdminEmail` returns `undefined`. You need to both `await` that function as it contains a database query and also return a value. Adding `return` before `SuperAdminListModel.find` should be enough.

---

Edit:

While it's not a syntax error, what you've done in your edit— `await function getAdminEmail() {}` —makes little sense.

Since you're using async/await, you can simply things. The following is untested. I'm assuming you're using something like Mongoose for your database, but you didn't specify.

```js
async function getAdminEmail(){
    const users = await SuperAdminListModel.find({}).exec();
    if (!users[0]) {
        throw new Error('No admin found');
    }
    console.log(users[0].superadmin_email);
    return users[0].superadmin_email;
}

// Elsewhere in your code:
let admin_email;
try {
    admin_email = await getAdminEmail();
} catch (err) {
    // You can't call res.status() in getAdminEmail, so
    // you should catch any errors it throws then do it here
    // in your request handler.
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err });
}
```

---

As a side note unrelated to your original question: `getAdminEmail` will try to call `res.status()` when there's an error, but variable `res` is not in scope and will throw an error when you try to use it.

Comment: My sincere apologies, i am just starting out with this, can you show me programatically what u mean?

Comment: Please See edits

Comment: You should `await` the _result_ of a function that returns promises, not the function definition itself. I am assuming your `.exec()` function returns a Promise if not given a callback, so you can simplify your code a lot. The alternative is to wrap the query in `return new Promise((res,next) => { ... });` but that's very verbose.

Comment: pls see edits of the code i want to show now

Comment: The error says what's wrong: the e-mail address is not a valid e-mail address. There are two extraneous single quotes: `"'*****************@gmail.com'"`

Comment: how do i get rid of the two commas?